# Building Rails Forms for saving Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations, form-for

I have categories model which I would like to be able to use with different models. That's how I ended up using Polymorphic with has_many.

With Rails_admin everything works without a problem. But, when I want to create a form by myself, I can't seem to make it save. Here is what I have:

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizings, inverse_of: :category, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cars, through: :categorizings, :source => :categorizable,
         :source_type => 'Car'
end
```

categorizing.rb

```
class Categorizing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :categorizable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

car.rb

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizings, :as => :categorizable, inverse_of: :car, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizings
end
```

vendor.rb

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizings, :as => :categorizable, inverse_of: :vendor, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizings
end
```

cars_controller.rb

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @car = Car.new
  end
  def create
    @car = current_user.cars.build(car_params)
        if @car.save
      redirect_to @car
        else
            render 'new'
        end
  end
  private
  def car_params
    params.require(:car).permit(:name, :details, :type, :category_ids => [] )
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "categorizings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "category_id"
  t.integer  "categorizable_id"
  t.string   "categorizable_type"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "categorizings", ["categorizable_type", "categorizable_id"], name: "index_categorizings_on_categorizable_type_and_categorizable_id", using: :btree
```

This is what I have in the form

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name %>
```

And I receive this error:
Unpermitted parameter: category_ids

I am very confused right now and lost in models. Dont know this is the best approach or not. I would be glad if someone could tell me where I do the mistake.

Comment: Could you also include the contents of db/schema.rb?

Comment: added the schema.rb @pdoherty926

Answer (score 0):

Using this select_tag solved my problem

```
<%= f.select :category_ids, Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

but stops working if I disable multiple like

```
 :multiple => false
```